# Eclipse console throws a error and will not display

Tags: eclipse

The following version of Eclipse has been downloaded and installed:

*Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0)
Build id: 20201210-1552
OS: Windows 10, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32
Java version: 14.0.2*

Tomcat has been installed as a server.
However, when starting Tomcat, the following error appears:

[image]

The same error appears when selecting pom.xml and
*Run -> Maven build...*

The metadata log file shows the following exception;

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2021-03-01 16:18:22.275
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Creating console for C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin\javaw.exe (1 Mar 2021, 16:18:22)".
!STACK 0
java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: Cp65001
    at java.base/java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Charset.java:527)
    at org.eclipse.ui.console.IOConsole.<init>(IOConsole.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.views.console.ProcessConsole.<init>(ProcessConsole.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.views.console.ProcessConsoleManager$ConsoleCreation.run(ProcessConsoleManager.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

What is the correct way to resolve this?

Comment: What does "Details" show? Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. [Edit] your question to show us the extra detail.

Comment: question edited and exception from log file included, thanks

Comment: Java doesn't understand the CharSet "Cp65001". Try a different encoding - I think this is  specified in the Run Configuration for the launch, probably the "Encoding" value on the "Common" tab.